# How to deal with the label overlay in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label, overlay

I'm new to Python and tkinter and I'm trying to create a GUI with it. I'm trying to create new labels and comboboxes based on the selection of the first combobox. I have finished creating the first selectable combobox and bind the creation of new labels and comboboxes based on the choice selected in first combobox.

However, since different choice creates different number of labels and comboboxes, and some of them locate at the same positions of the frame, so the labels and comboboxes may overlay other which causes a chaos for user to read. The main problem is in the 'def createSystem(self, event)' function, since two for loops are used here, I don't know how to clear out the old labels/comboboxes that the first 'if condition' creates before creating the new ones when the programme meets the second 'if condition'.

There are two solution I tried so far, but neither of them worked successfully.

1. I tried to create a global list and push all the labels that's being created in the private function into it, so that I can use label.destory() to clear out all the labels and create new ones. However, the problem for this is that I don't know how to add the label that's being created into the list and how to delete before the second for loop starting to create the new ones.
2. I've thought of directly modify the text of the existing labels at specific rows, but since the labels are created using function 'ttk.Label()' directly without being assigned to any variable, so that I cannot address them and do some modification on them. If I would like to assign them to different variables, I will need to create variables at the same time in the for loop, which I googled is said to be a bad thing although it is doable in Python.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


cc_category = {'zxcv': ["vzxcv"], 'qeqL': ["safx"]}

ab_type = ["sfda", "fsdf"]
bbbbList = {
               'sddd':["1","2","3","4"],
               'ssss sdddd':["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "2500", "4500"], 
               'assss sssaz':["BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BWD", "BWA"], 
               'asdf Cfsdfsddf':["1"], 
               'asdf fasdfs' :["1"], 
               'asdf zxxxxxx':["1"], 
               'cccc xxxxxxx':["1"], 
               'cccc saddddL':["1","2","4","42","2"], 
               'zxxx xvzzzzL':["1","2","3"], 
               'cvcv cccxxxc':["2","2","EPDM","3","3","4","4","82","122","333"], 
               }

aaaaLabelList = {'wwww':[], 
                     'qqqq':[], 
                     'hjfgjhk':[], 
                     'xzvxzcvx':[],
                     'qweaddddz':[], 
                     'qweasd':[],
                     'utyiuiufturt':[],
                     'zxcvxzbvc':[],
                     'fdass':[],
                     'ffdasdd':[], 
                     'fsdfaL':[],
                     'fdasfzxAL':[],
                     'fdsafdL':[],
                     'Dasdfszxd':[], 
                     'dasfsdfsadE':[],
                     'FIRE SAFE':[], 
                     'rrrr':[], 
                     'eeee':[]}

framelist = []
frames = 1
labellist = [20]

class Root (tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("sssssss")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.InitUI()



    def getUpdateData(self, event):
        self.cb['values'] = cc_category[self.ValveTypeCombo.get()]



    def add_frame(self):
        global frames
        framelist.append(tk.Frame(root))
        framelist[-1].grid()
        frames += 1

    def delete_frame(self):
        global frames
        framelist.remove(tk.Frame(root))
        framelist[-1].detory()
        frames -= 1

    def createSystem(self, event):

        if self.labelCombo.get() == "zxcv":
            for labelname in bbbbList:   
                ttk.Label(self, text = labelname + ":     ").grid(column = 0, row = list(bbbbList).index(labelname) + 2) 
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = bbbbList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = list(bbbbList).index(labelname) + 2)




        if self.labelCombo.get() == "qeqL":
            for labelname in aaaaLabelList:   
                ttk.Label(self, text = labelname + ":     ").grid(column = 0, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2) 
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = aaaaLabelList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2)



    def InitUI(self):
        self.label_1 = ttk.Label(self,text = "asss dddd:    ")
        self.label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)


        self.labelCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 5, state = 'readonly', values = list(cc_category.keys()))
        self.labelCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.createSystem)

        self.labelCombo.grid(column = 1, row = 0)





if __name__== '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

Below are the code I wrote to pass labels that's being created in the for loop to a global list. But it has a compile error in it:

```
line 77, in createSystem
   labellist[i].grid(column = 0, row = list(bbbbList).index(labelname) + 2)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

I don't know how to deal with it.

Here are the full code for my first thought that didn't work:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


cc_category = {'zxcv': ["vzxcv"], 'qeqL': ["safx"]}

ab_type = ["sfda", "fsdf"]
bbbbList = {
               'sddd':["1","2","3","4"],
               'ssss sdddd':["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "2500", "4500"], 
               'assss sssaz':["BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BWD", "BWA"], 
               'asdf Cfsdfsddf':["1"], 
               'asdf fasdfs' :["1"], 
               'asdf zxxxxxx':["1"], 
               'cccc xxxxxxx':["1"], 
               'cccc saddddL':["1","2","4","42","2"], 
               'zxxx xvzzzzL':["1","2","3"], 
               'cvcv cccxxxc':["2","2","EPDM","3","3","4","4","82","122","333"], 
               }

aaaaLabelList = {'wwww':[], 
                     'qqqq':[], 
                     'hjfgjhk':[], 
                     'xzvxzcvx':[],
                     'qweaddddz':[], 
                     'qweasd':[],
                     'utyiuiufturt':[],
                     'zxcvxzbvc':[],
                     'fdass':[],
                     'ffdasdd':[], 
                     'fsdfaL':[],
                     'fdasfzxAL':[],
                     'fdsafdL':[],
                     'Dasdfszxd':[], 
                     'dasfsdfsadE':[],
                     'FIRE SAFE':[], 
                     'rrrr':[], 
                     'eeee':[]}

framelist = []
frames = 1
labellist = [20]

class Root (tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("sssssss")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.InitUI()



    def getUpdateData(self, event):
        self.cb['values'] = cc_category[self.ValveTypeCombo.get()]



    def add_frame(self):
        global frames
        framelist.append(tk.Frame(root))
        framelist[-1].grid()
        frames += 1

    def delete_frame(self):
        global frames
        framelist.remove(tk.Frame(root))
        framelist[-1].detory()
        frames -= 1

    def createSystem(self, event):

        if self.labelCombo.get() == "zxcv":
            for i, labelname in zip(range(20),bbbbList):
                root.add_frame()
                labellist.append(tk.Frame(root))
                ttk.Label(framelist[i], text = labelname + ":     ")
                labellist[i].grid(column = 0, row = list(bbbbList).index(labelname) + 2) 
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = bbbbList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = list(bbbbList).index(labelname) + 2)
                i += 1



        if self.labelCombo.get() == "qeqL":
            for labelname in aaaaLabelList:   
                ttk.Label(self, text = labelname + ":     ").grid(column = 0, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2) 
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = aaaaLabelList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2)



    def InitUI(self):
        self.label_1 = ttk.Label(self,text = "asss dddd:    ")
        self.label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)


        self.labelCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 5, state = 'readonly', values = list(cc_category.keys()))
        self.labelCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.createSystem)

        self.labelCombo.grid(column = 1, row = 0)





if __name__== '__main__':
    root = Root()
    root.mainloop()
```

I would like to see the labels and comboboxes not overlaying each other when I switch the value thats being selected in the first combobox at the mean time, being able to access the values thats being selected in all the new created comboboxes for further use. For example, I can create a submit button to submit all the values selected in the comboboxes which are created after the selection of the first combobox.

### Edited

I have edited the createSystem function, it can be compiled now, but the problem is that is seems keep adding labels to the 'framelist[]', I tried to add 'framelist[i].destroy() in the for loop to destroy the current label, but it returns

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'framelist'
```

Here's the code for the new 'createSystem' function:

```
def createSystem(self, event):

        if self.labelCombo.get() == "zxcv":
            for i, labelname in zip(range(len(bbbbList)),bbbbList):
                root.add_frame()
                #labellist.append(tk.Frame(root))
                ttk.Label(framelist[i], text = labelname).grid()
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = bbbbList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = i + 1)



        if self.labelCombo.get() == "qeqL":
            for i, labelname in zip(range(len(aaaaLabelList)),aaaaLabelList):  
                ttk.Label(self, text = labelname + ":     ").grid(column = 0, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2) 
                ttk.Combobox(self, width = 10, state = 'readonly', values = aaaaLabelList.get(labelname)).grid(column = 1, row = list(aaaaLabelList).index(labelname) + 2)
```

Comment: your `labellist` is `[20]` so you try to do `20.grid(...)` and you get error `'int' object has no attribute 'grid'`

Comment: @furas Thank you for the reply, I have edited it and it seems working now, and the labels can be added to the framelist now. However, I still cannot destroy the labels in the list, and each time when I switch between the two options in the first combobox, it keeps adding new labels to the framelist. I know it is because each time I select one item from the first combobox, it creates new labels, but the problem is I don't know how to delete the labels thats being stored in the framelist, do you know how to address them and delete them? Thank you.

Comment: do you get error message when you try to `destroy()` every label on list ? After destroying Label you may have to remove it from list too - `list.pop(index)` or `del list[index]`. If you remove all labels then (after destroying all labels) you can assign empty list to variable.

Answer (score 0):

Better to create the `label+combo` lists (`aaaaList` and `bbbbLabelList`) inside individual frame in `InitUI(...)` first, then switch between the frames in `createSystem(...)`.

Below are the modified `InitUI()` and `createSystem()`:

```
def createSystem(self, event):
    # get the frame based on selection of labelCombo
    frame = self.frames[self.labelCombo.get()]
    # show the frame
    frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nsew')
    frame.tkraise()

def InitUI(self):
    self.label_1 = ttk.Label(self,text = "asss dddd:    ")
    self.label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

    self.labelCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, width = 5, state = 'readonly', values = list(cc_category.keys()))
    self.labelCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.createSystem)
    self.labelCombo.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

    self.frames = {} # hold the frames containing the label+combo list
    self.comboboxes = {} # hold the comboboxes in the frames
    for category in cc_category.keys():
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        selectedList = bbbbList if category == "zxcv" else aaaaLabelList
        for row, labelname in enumerate(selectedList):
            ttk.Label(frame, text=labelname+":     ").grid(column=0, row=row) 
            combobox = ttk.Combobox(frame, width=10, state='readonly', values=selectedList.get(labelname))
            combobox.grid(column=1, row=row)
            self.comboboxes[labelname] = combobox
        self.frames[category] = frame
```

Comment: And how do I get the item that I selected since we are using ttk.Combobox(frame, width=10, state='readonly', values=selectedList.get(labelname)).grid(column=1, row=row) to create combobox. The combobox thats  created have no variable name assigned to them, so we cannot use combobox.get() to get the item thats selected. Can you give some advice? Thank you!

Comment: You can create a dictionary to save the comboboxes.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply! I have figured it out by using the dictionary to manage them.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that you were not destroying the previous widgets before creating new ones ( hence the overlap ). I have made your code satisfy your need (hope so).
Wish this would be helpful

```py
    def delete_frames(self):
        # By using [2:] we are sparing the first combobox
        # Though I recommend creating these comboboxes in seperate frame
        if self.winfo_children()[2:] != []:
            for widget in self.winfo_children()[2:]:
                widget.destroy()
                # Fully Removing by calling destroy can also use hide
```

```py
    def createSystem(self, event):
        self.delete_frames()
        to_use = bbbbList if self.labelCombo.get() == "zxcv" else aaaaLabelList
        global framelist
        i = 1
        for item in to_use.items():
            tk.Label(self, text=item[0]).grid(column=0, row=i)
            ttk.Combobox(self, width=10, state='readonly',
                         values=item[1]).grid(column=1, row=i)
            i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the reply, it helps a ton!

Comment: You are welcome.Please make sure to mark helpful comments or upvote them